# Tree in C++11 tuple with RTTI

Tags: c++, c++11, tree, tuples, rtti

I want to implement a simple tree in C++11 tuple with a Python fashion. In Python, we can use type(obj) to check run-time object type, and pass object with different type to one function, I have write pseudo code for calc(), how to do it in c++?

I try to print typeid(child1).name() and typeid(tree).name(), they are 'St5tupleIIciiEE' and 'St5tupleIIcS_IIciiEES0_EE'.

My environment is g++ 4.8.1. Thanks!

```
// pseudo code
int calc(tuple tree) {
  symbol = type(get<0>(tree));
  l_child = type(get<1>(tree));
  r_child = type(get<2>(tree));

  l = (type(l_child) == tuple) ? calc(l_child) : l_child;
  r = (type(r_child) == tuple) ? calc(r_child) : r_child;

  return l symbol r;
}

int main() 
{
  auto l_child = make_tuple('*', 1, 2);
  auto r_child = make_tuple('-', 5, 1);
  auto tree = make_tuple('+', l_child, r_child);

  cout << calc(tree) << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Python and C++ are very different languages. C++ is statically typed, Python is not. Transplanting Python techniques to C++ may or may not work. In this case it won't work.

In Python, there is only one tuple class, able to represent any tuple; in C++ there is an infinite number of tuple types, each one able to hold specific kinds of data. They are not interchangeable, as your experiment with `typeid` aptly demonstrates.

In C++, you cannot hold an arbitrary tree in a tuple. Write a tree class (or better, a class template).

**Edit**: technically, if you combine tuples with pointers and unions, you can get away with tuples. This is however not recommended. Your tree is going to be your central abstraction, exposing such low level details as pointers and unions is counterproductive and should be avoided. The C++ way is to write a class, stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's unreal, since result of `typeid().name` is implementation-defined.

> ```
> const char* name() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns: An implementation-defined ntbs.

However, here, you cannot use ternary operator, since `calc(l_child)` will be evaluated at compile-time, so if `l_child` is not tuple, compilation will be failed.

You can use some type-traits (or overloading), since `tuple` members are known at compile-time.

```
int calc(int value)
{
    return value;
}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
int calc(const std::tuple<char, Left, Right>& tuple)
{
   char symbol = std::get<0>(tuple);
   Left l_child = std::get<1>(tuple);
   Right r_child = std::get<2>(tuple);
   int l = calc(l_child);
   int r = calc(r_child);
   return l /*symbol*/, r;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ybYmX7)